# Collecting all columns NOT from datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

**Situation:**

I'm creating a minimal client for creating user reports. The main form features a grid with some of the most important columns in the .XSD file and a menu item called "Custom Reports." When the user clicks "Custom Reports" a form with all the columns available in the grid materializes.

**Here's the rub:**

Right now my code references all the columns in the grid of the main form. I want to know if there is a way to reference all the columns of the .XSD, obviously I don't think the user needs all those columns on the main form, but he could at some point. I do not want to create a separate hidden table to reference either. Others around here have suggested that.

I am open to suggestions, but instincts tell me there should be some way to gather this information from the definition XSD file.

Comment: Im beginning to think this is impossible to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the only way so far to do this is to fill a temporary dataset with the tables I need then query the dataset to see how many fields are in it. If anybody has a better idea. Please let me know.